# Passing predetermined parameters to scipy.optimize.fsolve

Tags: python, scipy, nonlinear-functions

I'm trying to use python to solve a system of 6 nonlinear equations. There are 9 variables, and 3 of them are predetermined (leaving a system of 6 equations with 6 unknowns). The problem is, it could be any 3, I have no way of knowing beforehand.

Here are the equations (if you're interested).

c11*c12 + c21*c22 + c31*c32 = 0

c11*c13 + c21*c23 + c31*c33 = 0

c12*c13 + c22*c23 + c32*c33 = 0

c11*c21 + c12*c22 + c13*c23 = 0

c11*c31 + c12*c32 + c13*c33 = 0

c21*c31 + c22*c32 + c23*c33 = 0

---

Note: This is the way I assumed would be quickest/easiest to solve. Another possible expression is:

```
    |c11 c21 c31|
A = |c12 c22 c32|
    |c13 c23 c33|

    |c11 c12 c13|
B = |c21 c22 c23|
    |c31 c32 c33|

      |1 0 0|
A*B = |0 1 0|
      |0 0 1|
```

---

**My question is: is there anyway to set 3 of these as fixed, and have scipy.optimize.fsolve (or a more appropriate module?) solve for the remaining parameters?**

Answer (score 0):

So, I found a valid solution myself. Not sure if it's the best solution, but it's functional.

To answer my question, scipy.optimize.fsolve takes a parameter args = (extra arguments here). I put the predetermined parameters in here. When the function is called, the args are first parsed and the 3 predetermined values placed in the appropriate spot.

The remaining 6 variables are passed in a list, and are iterated over to fill the remaining gaps. Since the arguments are not changing, each variable is always placed in the same spot in the matrix.

Using this method, any 3 matrix elements can be predetermined, and fsolve will attempt to determine the remainder.

The calling statement for fsolve looks like this:

```
paramSolve1, infodict, ier, mesg = scipy.optimize.fsolve(func,(i,i,i,i,i,i),args = (knownVals[0],knownVals[1],knownVals[2]), full_output = True, warning = False)
```

knwonVals is a list of predetermined parameters, and i is a starting guess (all 6 missing parameters get the same starting guess). full_output allows the optional outputs to be returned, and warning = False turns off the warning message present when a solution isn't found. For more information, check out http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html

For those interested, the entire code for the problem is below.

```
import scipy
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

def func(params, *args):
    c = propMatrix(createMatrix(args), params)

    ans =(scipy.dot(c[:, 0],c[:, 1]), scipy.dot(c[:, 1],c[:, 2]), scipy.dot(c[:, 0],c[:, 2]),scipy.dot(c[:, 0],c[:, 0])-1,scipy.dot(c[:, 1],c[:, 1])-1,scipy.dot(c[:, 2],c[:, 2])-1)
    return ans

def createMatrix(knownVals):

    c = [['____', '____', '____'],['____', '____', '____'], ['____', '____', '____']]  

    for element in knownVals:
        x, y, val = element
        c[y][x] = float(val)
    return c

def propMatrix(c, params):
    for p in params:
        assign = True
        for x in range(3):
            for y in range(3):
                if c[x][y]=='____' and assign:
                    c[x][y] = float(p)
                    assign = False

    return scipy.array(c)

def test(c):
    v1 = c[:, 0]
    v2 = c[:, 1]
    v3 = c[:, 2]
    h1 = c[0, :]
    h2 = c[1, :]
    h3 = c[2, :]
    ans = (scipy.dot(v1,v1)-1, scipy.dot(v1,v2), scipy.dot(v1, v3), scipy.dot(v2, v2)-1, scipy.dot(v2, v3), scipy.dot(v3,v3)-1, scipy.dot(h1,h1)-1, scipy.dot(h1,h2), scipy.dot(h1, h3), scipy.dot(h2, h2)-1, scipy.dot(h2, h3), scipy.dot(h3,h3)-1)
    return ans

def getInput():
    knownVals = []
    print """\n\nThis module analytically solves for the rotation matrix\n
    First, enter 3 known values of the matrix:\n
                 x
            1    2    3   
       1 | c11  c12  c13 |
    y  2 | c21  c22  c23 |
       3 | c31  c32  c33 |\n\n"""

    for i in range(3):
        invalid = True
        print "Point Number %i:"%(i)
        while invalid:
            x = int(raw_input("\tx-coordinate:"))-1
            if x>2 or x<0:
                print "\tInvalid x-coordinate."
            else:
                invalid = False
        invalid = True
        while invalid:
            y = int(raw_input("\ty-coordinate:"))-1
            if y>2 or y<0:
                print "\tInvalid y-coordinate."
            else:
                invalid = False
        invalid = True
        while invalid:
            val = float(raw_input("\tValue:"))
            if val>1 or val<-1:
                print "\tInvalid value. Must be -1 <= value <= 1"
            else:
                invalid = False
        knownVals.append((x, y, val))
    c = createMatrix(knownVals)
    print "Input Matrix:\n\n", scipy.array(c)
    choice = raw_input("\nIs this correct (y/n)?  ")
    if choice == "y":
        return knownVals
    elif choice == "n":
        return getInput()

def Main():
    solution = False
    knownVals = getInput()
    for i in (-1,-.5,0,.5,1):
        paramSolve1, infodict, ier, mesg = scipy.optimize.fsolve(func,(i,i,i,i,i,i),args = (knownVals[0],knownVals[1],knownVals[2]), full_output = True, warning = False)
        if ier == 1:
            print "\nInitial value: %r"%(i) 
            print propMatrix(createMatrix(knownVals),paramSolve1)
            solution = True
    if not solution:
        print "Could not find a valid solution"

scipy.set_printoptions(precision = 4, suppress = True)
Main()
```